# Caddy2 - Routing with php_fastcgi and path

Tags: php, url-routing, caddy, caddyfile

I'm running a `Caddy` server with `php` on `localhost`
My server is running perfectly on the main path : `http://x.x.x.x/index.php`.
This is my initial configuration :

```
x.x.x.x:80 {


        root * /var/www/html 

        php_fastcgi php:9000

        file_server

}
```

If I try to serve my php over another path `http://x.x.x.x/dashboard/index.php`, it will always return "file not found" :

```
x.x.x.x:80 {


        root * /var/www/html

        php_fastcgi /dashboard/*  php:9000

        file_server

}
```

or :

```
x.x.x.x:80 {

        route /dashboard/* {
                root * /var/www/html

                php_fastcgi php:9000

                file_server

        }

}
```

I don't really understand.

Comment: For peoples having this issue, 1/ Use `/var/www` for the root of  your website, but not any other folder. 2/ PHP as cgi runs as www-data user, without php-fpm owning that folder it won't work, it will return "File not found", the solution is to `chown www-data:www-data /var/www`, and it should work straightaway after restarting Caddy. Make sure to modify the Caddyfile with `root * /var/www` It's not a php-fpm issue, nor a Caddy server issue, even if it looks a lot likes it.

Answer (score 0):

For the PHP server, there is a separate root setting that is required for the php-fpm service to serve the correct file.

```
{
  http_port  80
  https_port 443
}

:80 {
  log {
    output stdout
  }

  # static files location on the Caddy server
  root /var/www/html
  file_server

  php_fastcgi /dashboard/* php:9000 {
    # PHP files location on the PHP server 
    root /www
  }
}
```

The `/www` refers to the root directory on the php server so you will need to adjust it too the actual root.  You may also need to adjust the configuration based on the URI path.  In your example, all PHP files would need to reside in `/path/to/php/dashboard/*.php`.  I assume there is a way to make the path invisible to the backend but I haven't fiddled enough.

If this is a docker-based implementation, you can redirect `access.log = /proc/self/fd/2` to see the PHP service requests in the logs. Particularly useful in docker-compose setups.  The output will look something like:

```
php      | 192.168.208.3 -  28/Jun/2023:12:51:10 +0000 "GET /events/index.php" 200 -
```

For which the PHP file is located at `/www/events/index.php` on the PHP server. This is a result of the `root /www` directive in the Caddyfile being appended to the URI path `/events/index.php` during the request to the fcgi backend.

Comment: The php.ini setting for the access log format I use is `access.format = "%R - %u %t \"%m %r\" %s %{Content-Type}o"`